# Jetty: unpack .war to specific folder

Tags: java, jetty, war

I need to run Jetty, specify war-file and have it unpacked by Jetty into specific location. The common behavior of Jetty is to take TEMP directory or JETTY_HOME/work directory and unpack war-file into a sub-folder named like this: jetty-HOST-PORT-CONTEXT.war-_-any-
This is absolutely inappropriate for our environment because the PORT part is random. War-file must be unpacked by Jetty and the destination must be 100% flexible.

Is it possible? Please advice. Jetty isn’t my area of expertise, forgive me if the question is lame or trivial, however googling didn’t help much.

Thank you very much!

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications#Deploying_Webapps?

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you need this behaviour? I have a feeling you're trying to solve the wrong problem...

Comment: @Tim there is an application which must start jetty in the following manner: command-to-start-jetty PORT path-to-war-file path-where-to-put-extracted-war-file.
The application takes control of workers and sets random available port at start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you everyone. I’ve managed to achieve the requirement extending Jetty with the following code:

```
int port = 8080;
String context_path = "/";
File tmp_directory = "C:\\some-custom-path\\";
String war_path = "C:\\path-to-a\\file.war";

WebAppContext app = new WebAppContext();
app.setContextPath( context_path );
app.setWar( war_path );
app.setTempDirectory( tmp_directory );

Server server = new Server( port );
server.setHandler( app );
server.start();
server.join();
```

*app.setTempDirectory* call makes Jetty unpack war-file into custom folder. I’ve not found any other way but the solution suits me right.

Answer (score 1):

(not tried it, just reading from the wiki page  [jetty wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Creating_a_Server))
You could extract the war to a predefined direcory. And then provide that folder as setWar argument.

```
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    webapp.setWar(jetty_home+"/webapps/testlocation/");
    server.setHandler(webapp);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is that possible via configuration files?